# How to return IEnumerable instead of string with conditions in foreach?

Tags: c#, linq

What approach do I have to make, to make something like the method below to work for `IEnumerable<Flight>` instead of string? I want to manipulate my `IEnumerable<Flight>` source(in parameter) with conditions written in method, and return `IEnumerable<Flight>` based on those conditions only. So If those conditions are not met, I don't wath that `IEnumerable<Flight>` returns records for that item.

```
public string FilterFlights(IEnumerable<Flight> flights)
{
    string s = "";
    foreach (var flight in flights)
    {
        var indexItem = 0;
        DateTime previousArrivalDateTime = new DateTime();
        TimeSpan timeSpan;

        int time = 0;
        foreach (var segments in flight.Segments)
        {
            if (indexItem == 0)
            {
                previousArrivalDateTime = segments.ArrivalDate;
                s = s + "Departure: " + segments.DepartureDate + ", Arrival: " + segments.ArrivalDate + "; ";
            }

            if (indexItem > 0)
            {
                timeSpan = segments.DepartureDate - previousArrivalDateTime;
                time += timeSpan.Hours;
                s = s + "Departure: " + segments.DepartureDate + ", Arrival: " + segments.ArrivalDate + "; ";
                previousArrivalDateTime = segments.ArrivalDate;
            }
            indexItem++;
        }

        if (time > 2)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Classes:

```
    public class Flight
{
    public IList<Segment> Segments { get; set; }
}

public class Segment
{
    public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: And return what?  `IEnumerable<What>` ?

Comment: Your requirement and your code seem to be about very different things. I see a _different_ operation on the first but no filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a `IEnumerable<T>` and call `yield return T`;

E.g.

```
public IEnumerable<string> FilterFlights(IEnumerable<Flight> flights)
{
    foreach (var flight in flights)
    {
        var indexItem = 0;
        DateTime previousArrivalDateTime = new DateTime();
        TimeSpan timeSpan;

        int time = 0;
        foreach (var segments in flight.Segments)
        {
            if (indexItem == 0)
            {
                previousArrivalDateTime = segments.ArrivalDate;
                yield return "Departure: " + segments.DepartureDate + ", Arrival: " + segments.ArrivalDate + "; ";
            }

            if (indexItem > 0)
            {
                timeSpan = segments.DepartureDate - previousArrivalDateTime;
                time += timeSpan.Hours;
                yield return "Departure: " + segments.DepartureDate + ", Arrival: " + segments.ArrivalDate + "; ";
                previousArrivalDateTime = segments.ArrivalDate;
            }
            indexItem++;
        }
    }

}
```

this way you can use it like this:

I hope this is what you want.

```
foreach(string text in FilterFlights(flights))
    Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: I fixed, I would like to return `IEnumerable<Flight>`. Sorry that I didn't write before.

Comment: I just showed you how to return an IEnumerable<T>, all you have to do is correct the code to suite your needs, it should be fairly easy.

Comment: Thanks I understand, I made things working with your help. I needed it like this (direct copy of my method) http://pastebin.com/qCFZCYeC